# Extract word from specified string with regex delimited by tab

Tags: regex

I have specified line between comma, with strings delimited by tab(\t):

`"2016 INFO    2016-01-01 10:00:00,000 String1 String2 40        Comments are here"`.

I've used this expression `(\t)(.*?)(\t)` but didn't working.

I need an expression to extract only word String1 with regex and another expression to extract String2.

Also if an explanation is included it would be helpful.

Comment: `\d+\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\d+`

Comment: which regex flavor ? .NET ? Java ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input:

> 2016 INFO    2016-01-01 10:00:00,000 String1 String2 40        Comments are here"

pattern to be matched - `string1` and `string2`

to match `string1` - `/,\d+\s+(\S+)/`

to match `string2` - `/,\d+\s+\S+\s*(\S+)/`

**Explanation:**

`\d` - matches any digit character(0-9)

`\s` - matches any whitespace character.

`\S` - matches any character that is not a whitespace character.

`+` - match one or more of the preceding token.

`*` - match zero or more of the preceding token.

Use [this](http://regexr.com/) website to test out regex.

Comment: This extract for string1: ",000 String1" and for string2: ",000 String1 String2".

Comment: @CatalinMarian, the capture group `()` makes sure that you can get the `string1` and `string2`.

Comment: It is possible to remove first 5 characters ",000 "?

Comment: You can find in this [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) an example on how to capture groups in Java.

Comment: I have used that, and was returned every time only match from group(0).

Comment: @Catalin, what does group(0) return?

Comment: for: /,\\d+\\s+(\\S+)/ - have no match
for: (\\t)(.*?)(\\t)(.*?)(\\t)(.*?)(\\t)
Found value group1:  INFO 2016-01-01 10:00:00,000 
Found value group2:  
Found value group3: INFO

Comment: @Catalin, Can you please post the code that you have tried by editing the question?

Comment: Now is working with this regex: ",(\\d+)(\\t)(.*?)(\\t)(.*?)(\\t)" and capturing group from group(*) Java code. Thanks!

Comment: @Catalin awesome :) Please accept/upvote the answer if it helped.